# Test Projects Conversion

Tags: visual-studio, tdd

I apologize. This is part rant, part question.

For the rant: Dear MS developers who post MVC projects on CodePlex and dedicate their sites to MVC with TDD: I love to learn from you and thanks for the examples, but not everyone has Pro. I'm sick of not being able to load the test project portion of these things because  use Standard, which more than covers most needs [with Nunit]. It's annoying.

Now, for the question. :-)

Is there a tool out there to convert these unit test projects to a proj file Studio Standard can open so I can at least compile and view the code?

--

P.S. Dear Microsoft: Enough with not including unit testing with all versions of Studio already. It's silly. Testing is not just an "enterprise" or "pro" feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, switching between test frameworks is just a case of search/replace. If the csproj doesn't load, just create a new project file and drag the code files in and fix them afterwards (along with the references). TestDriven.NET, for example (or NUnit console) are perfectly happy with just a dll/exe as the test project.

Maybe a pain, but not necessarily a huge problem.

If you want to use NUnit with MVC, there are brief instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381614.aspx) and [here](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2008/02/aspnet-mvc-test-framework-integration.html) - I don't know (haven't tested) whether they apply to Standard.